# Add to database cache from django_crontab

Tags: django, cron

I added settings for django_crontab

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'django_crontab',
    ....
```

]

and setting for cron

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'app.cron.task'),
]
```

add task method to app.cron

```
from .views import add_to_cache_table()


def task():
    add_to_cache_table()
```

and created method add_to_cache_table() in app.views:

```
from django.core.cache import cache


def add_to_cache_table():
   cache.add('key', 'value')
```

But, when I'm trying to get value form cache by that key, I get None. 
Can i use database cache in cron and write to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting service (Pythonanywhere) doesn't support crontab for users.

https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/issues/14

Comment: on PythonAnywhere you should use their scheduled tasks instead of setting up crontab yourself